# Anyone know what this stone building is?

Tags: 19th-century, united-kingdom, building

It's located next to a beach and below a small hill. It has three sides and a large metal grid on top, on each of the three sides is an arch which tapers down toward a small opening on the ground. I came across it while walking a coastal path in wales.  I have no idea what it is, or what its purpose could be ... does anyone know please?

It's located on a beach between Clarach bay and Borth. It looks like a small castle (without any turrets) and stands about 10 feet tall. The beach is very secluded it's not one used by tourists. Not sure if that helps or not

[image: Photo of stone building]

Comment: I believe you need more then 10 rep points to post images. Can you give a more precise location, that might help narrow it down

Comment: You should have enough reputation to post images now. Can you [edit] the question to add the image? Thank you!

Comment: It's located on a beach between clarach bay and borth. It looks like a small castle (without any turrets) and stands about 10 feet tall. The beach is very secluded it's not one used by tourists. Not sure if that helps or not, it's a shame I can't post the photo!

Comment: Seems it's a [disused lime kiln](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-the-ceredigion-coastal-path-at-wallog-between-clarach-and-borth-on-78920641.html)

Comment: Wow, that's impressive I would never have been able to find that. Thank you, mystery solved

Comment: I can't speak for @sempaiscuba but it's partly a matter of knowing what you're looking for. I saw your photo and thought "lime kiln"; from that point, it's probably not hard to confirm.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a "[single pot lime kiln](http://www.brocross.com/industrial%20history/welsh%20limekilns/ceredigion/wallog.htm)", adjacent to the beach, at [Wallog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallog).

Coal and limestone would have been landed on the beach from small sailing vessels. The burnt lime would then be used to improve the local acidic soils.

There are a number of these [kilns](https://www.ceredigion.gov.uk/index.cfm?articleid=16837) in Ceredigion. This particular kiln dates to the early nineteenth century, and is described by [Cadw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadw) as "a particularly fine example".

[More details](http://www.coflein.gov.uk/en/site/40656/details/wallog-limekiln), including links to further archive items relating to Wallog Lime Kiln, are available in the online database for the National Monuments Record of Wales, Coflein. (Thanks to Nathan Cooper for the link in the comments below).

Comment: What century is it from?

Comment: [Early 19th century](http://www.coflein.gov.uk/en/site/40656/details/wallog-limekiln)